Good tire for commuting
I have been using a Panaracer Tour Guard Plus for the past 2 years (42 mm this past year, and 32 mm the prior year).
My observation is that the 42 is considerably slower and the bike feels sluggish even without my commuting gear on it.  While the 42 has more volume, to have a similar rolling resistance as the 32 (based on feel), I need to run the pressure higher which seems to defeat the point of a wider tire.  I don't have any metrics capturing my power output so this is based on what I 'feel'.
I feel that the benefits I get with the 42 is the mechanical grip when cornering that I don't necessarily have with the 32 and in the same vein, more mechanical grip when taking the bike on gravel.  It feels like the bike is planted when cornering aggressively and affords me some tolerance if I hit gravel or debris mid corner.  While I can run the pressure lower and make the ride more comfortable, at those pressures, the tire becomes slow.
Aside from that, I've not had a flat on those tires in either size and I get about 5000 mi on the rear tire, about 10k for the front.
That said:

I don't see the specs for the tire on bicyclerollingresistance.com - would it be most similar to https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/tour-reviews/panaracer-pasela-pt
If I'm looking for a faster tire that still affords puncture protection, and durability, would the Schwalbe Marathon be a better tire for that purpose?
Are there tubeless options which might be faster yet and would I be better off switching to tubeless?


The feel is usally very deceiving. The rolling resistance must be measured or at least the speed at the same power must be compared, not just feel.

The assumption that wider rolls faster is only true for supple tires that share the same casing structure and have the same compound, and it's not because a tire is the same product line that it will be the case. EDIT: To complement on @ojs's comment: on smooth surfaces (like BRR's drum), wider tires roll faster at the same pressure, but on rougher surfaces, wider tires can be set up at lower pressure for a similar rolling resistance on hard surfaces, but because of the lower pressure will be less impacted by the rough surface. This discussion happens mostly in the performance tires circles, as it's a use-case where compromises can be made to have lower rolling resistance (either on puncture resistance or cost).
Since you quote BRR, they for example made a comparison between the different widths of Schwalbe Marathon: the 32 is a clear outlier because of presumed different casing, with higher rolling resistance than the others. For the rest, narrower tires roll a bit faster in that comparison. It is at odds with performance tires, where wider tires roll faster.
The amount of puncture protection that you need depends on the specifics of your commute, and how clean are the streets: on perfectly cleaned streets, there is no need for a puncture resistant tires, and you can perfectly lower puncture resistance to improve comfort and/or rolling resistance. On my wife commuter's for example, I replaced the Marathon Plus by Marathon Almotion, as the streets on her commute are clean enough to not justify the absolute best protection. Changing the tire allowed to lower the pressure by 2 bars, so the comfort improvement was huge.
On switching to tubeless: tubeless is excellent for perforation and pinch flats, not so much against long cuts. Repairs on the roadside can also be easier (if it can be plugged by a bacon stripe/dynaplug). It's a good choice for commuting, if the kind of punctures you may face are among the ones that tubeless tires are good against. It needs a bit more attention than tubes (you need to make sure that you have enough sealant), but it's also a compromise that can certainly be worth it for certain kinds of commutes.

Note that product recommendations are off-topic here, so I won't write any in the answer. For the choice of the Marathon Almotion on my wife's commuter, I used Bicycle Rolling Resistance as starting point to narrow down my choice (I also need a slight off-road biais, so on this basis the Almotion is anyway not an absolute recommendation). I took the tubeless version, with the idea that I would convert it to tubeless in case of frequent punctures (attributable to lower puncture resistance), but it turns out to be an unnecessary precaution, as in two years, she didn't have had a single puncture.

A friend of mine doing absurd distances commuting counts the time saved by a faster tire combined with the odd flat tire repair against the lower speed of more puncture resistant tires. For him a faster tire with the odd flat wins. For me puncture resistance is more important. We ended up with the same tires.

While on the subject of BRR and "with performance tires, where wider tires roll faster" is true only if you run the tires at same pressure. Running tires at recommended pressure narrows the difference to barely measurable level: https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/specials/grand-prix-5000-s-tr-comparison

@ojs I updated the text to nuance my "claim", as cycling enables to ride on more varied surfaces that BRR's drum. Lower pressures (enabled by wider tires, it's not the wider tires that are better per se) perform better on rougher surfaces (not necessarily gravel, but also poorly maintained tarmac or cobbles).

I suppose the question I should have asked was, is it possible to have a tire that rolls fast, lasts forever, has great flat protection, and is comfortable?  Yes, I checked the BRR website and I believe it is possible to pick 2, but no more.  In that case, I need to prioritize those variables for me and my situation which might just boil down to the same tire, but in a different size or switching to tubeless.

@JohnDoe the problem with 'universal recommendations' is that commuting encompasses a huge variety of constraints, so commuting alone doesn't mean anything: to take my example, if I'd have to commute north, I'd prefer very wide tires with some puncture resistance (city with roads in bad state, cobbles, tram tracks, short distances), south I'd use rather fast tubeless gravel tires (forests and fields, min 10km). But if you haven't had flats, that certainly a sign you can compromise on puncture protection (and explore other sections, some all season road tires offer decent level of protection)
